# add lines before and after my function usind decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

Hello I have this code usinf python :

```
def test(a,b):
    print(a+b)
```

And I would like to create a decorator which allows to do sometinh like this :

```
def test1(a,b):
    print(a*b) # add this first line
    print(a+b)
    print(a-b) # add this last line
```

Actually I would like to do sometinh like this :

```
@my_decorator
def test(a,b):
    print(a+b)
```

which will be the same that the function test1. Is it possible ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Sort of. If `test` assigns anything to `a` or `b`, your decorator isn't going to be able to pick up the new values for `print(a-b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```py
def dec(f):
    def wrap(a, b):
        print(a * b)
        f(a, b)
        print(a - b)
    return wrap

@dec
def test(a, b):
    print(a + b)
```

Remember, by decorating `test` with `dec` you are replacing `test` with `wrap`.

```py
>>> test(4, 5)
20
9
-1
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to inserting those extra `print`s inside the wrapped function's definition, though, particularly if the wrapped function assigns to `a` or `b`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica what? if its not equivelent what is it then? if your wrapped functon changes the input values you gave, I think you have more issues than just struggling with a decorator. Functions accept parameters and return values.

Comment: Plenty of functions assign to their parameters just to skip the extra code for creating another variable to use. The intent isn't for the assignment to affect the caller's variables.

Comment: For example, you might have a function `def find(bst, element)` that searches a binary search tree for a value and assigns subtrees to `bst` as it traverses the tree instead of using a separate variable to hold the current node.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica what if, you have and `add` function that spins up a fan, that blows a fire, and pushes a rod that gently moves a kettle into the fire, and touches a small vibrating timer, when the timer finishes it shakes, that gently moves the blower, which stops blowing the fire, and the fire extinguishes. The water in the kettle is boiling by this point. I need a decorator that sends me an sms x seconds after the timer vibrates.